# Unable to Keep my config and controller in different files in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a config for my RouteProvider and a controller in a single Js file as shown below

```
    var empApp = angular.module('employee', ['ngRoute']);
empApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/ShowAll.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrlr1'
    }).when('/AddEmployee', {
        templateUrl: '/AddEmployee.html',

    }).when('/EditEmployee', {
        templateUrl: '/EditEmployee.html',

    }).when('/deleteEmployee', {
        templateUrl: '/deleteEmployee.html',

    });
})
.controller('mainCtrlr1', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $location.path('/');
    alert('Hi');
}]);
```

I want keep my config and Controller in two different files
1. Configs.js

```
var empApp = angular.module('employee', ['ngRoute']);
empApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/ShowAll.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrlr1'
    }).when('/AddEmployee', {
        templateUrl: '/AddEmployee.html',

    }).when('/EditEmployee', {
        templateUrl: '/EditEmployee.html',

    }).when('/deleteEmployee', {
        templateUrl: '/deleteEmployee.html',

    });
});
```

And my controller in Controller1.js as given below.

```
var empApp=angular.module('employee', ['ngRoute']);
empApp.controller('mainCtrlr1', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    //$location.path('/');
    alert('Hi');
}]);
```

Now i have given reference of these two files in my html as given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Lib/angular.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="Scripts/Services.js"></script>-->

    <script src="Scripts/Controller1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/conifgs.js"></script>
    <script src="Lib/angular-route.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="employee">

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my ShowAll.html code is as shown below

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrlr1">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="emp in GetAllEmployees()">
            <tr>
                <td>{{emp.EmployeeID}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Email}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.Age}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.telephone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

now when i execute with above changes, my controller is failing to register. However when my controller and config is in same js file, my application works fine.

Any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet `angular.module('employee', ['ngRoute'])` creates a new angular module.

Since you have this snippet twice (one in each new file), you will create two different angular modules.

**Solution:**

Keep the `var empApp = angular.module('employee', ['ngRoute']);` in the first js file that is imported in your html file.

In the second js file, replace the first line with `var empApp = angular.module('employee');`

To further clarify, `angular.module('employee', ['ngRoute'])` will create a new module and therefore needs to be executed first. `angular.module('employee')` will get a reference to the module that was already created and hence should be used in all subsequent js files that need a reference to the module.